# Why do I have an empty window when viewing "Top 200 Rows"?

Tags: ssms

I have added some data into my database via POST-Request and it seem to have worked. However, when opening my table in the ssms I only see a white window.

What can I try to fix this?
[image]

This is my version info window
[image]

Comment: What version of SSMS?

Comment: Is the SSMS UI frozen while this takes place?  Does re-starting help?  Are you able to query the table manually for even 1 row?

Comment: SSMS 18 has *some* support for SQL Server 2022, however, I (as does Microsoft) would suggest using SSMS 19 for 2022 instances.

Comment: It is not frozen. I also added version info. I am able to run queries and I can see the data in the table, but not edit it.

Comment: What do you mean by "edit it"? As in you can't run `ALTER` statements or `UPDATE` statements? What error do you get?

Comment: @Salatgurke: If you mean that you're right-clicking and selecting "Edit Top 200 rows" then *if you even need that functionality* it sounds like upgrading SSMS would be the first thing to try.

Comment: If you are using the "edit top 200 rows" 'feature' (can we even call it a feature when it's so buggy?), there is a better solution; Don't, just *don't*. Use appropriate `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements.